# How can I run the NEAR Network locally and use the NEAR Wallet locally too?

Tags: nearprotocol

How can I run the NEAR network locally and use a locally-run NEAR wallet to execute transactions on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a local, virtualized, NEAR Network with Kurtosis and point the NEAR Wallet running on another process to that network.

Read more on how to set up Kurtosis for local networks here: https://docs.near.org/develop/testing/kurtosis-localnet